# g++ and -fno-elide-constructors flag - compiler goof up or bug in the code?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code on g++ compiled with -fno-elide-constructors seems to give wrong result.  Without -fno-elide-constructors flag, it seems to work right.

1. Is this a bug in my program somewhere?  (As the experience shows, most likely that bug will jump out at me as soon as I finish posting this - if there is one!)
2. If not, what gives for the seemgly wrong result with -fno-elide-constructors flag?

---

```
#include <iostream>
/*
Compile with g++ -fno-elide-constructors and without the  
-fno-elide-constructors flag
 */

class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA() : myVal(100) {
        std::cout << "default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    ClassA(int iX) : myVal(iX) {
        std::cout << "constructor with int arg called" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "myVal: " << myVal << std::endl;
    }
    ~ClassA() {
    std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    ClassA(const ClassA&) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    /*
    ClassA(ClassA&&) {
        std::cout << "MOVE constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    ClassA& operator=(ClassA&& otherA){
        std::cout << "Move-Assignment Operator called" << std::endl;       
        return *this;
        }  */
    int get_myVal() {std::cout << "myVal: " <<  myVal << std::endl; return myVal;  }
private:
    int myVal;
};

ClassA  myFunc(int iN){
    auto myTmp = ClassA(iN);
    return myTmp;
}
int main()
{
    //auto a0 =  ClassA{200};  //myFunc(200);
    //ClassA b0 = a0;
    auto a0 = myFunc(300);
    std::cout << a0.get_myVal()  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time & responses. (My apologies for the bad formatting of the code - I tried and gave up!)

Comment: Format your code properly. If you gave up on that, you will gave up on making a program.

Comment: What results do you get? What is the actual output? And what is the expected output?

Comment: @Some Programmer dude:  The expected answer is what I got with RVO.  Now the reason for the discrepancy is apparent after Miles Budnek pointed out the bug.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to *tell* us the expected and actual results (by *showing* it to us). For the expected result it's simple, run your program and copy-paste (as text) the output into the question. For the expected output, you can use the actual output as base, and modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize `ClassA::myVal` in `ClassA`'s copy constructor.  Thus the value of `a0.myVal` is indeterminate since `a0` is initialized via copy-initialization.

This is revealed only when compiling with "-fno-elide-constructors" because the standard allows a compiler to elide copies even when it changes the observable behavior of the program.  In this case, when compiling without "-fno-elide-constructors", gcc constructs `a0` directly, without the intermediate constructors, and `a0.myVal` ends up being `300`.  When you explicitly disable copy elision, gcc keeps all of the intermediate copies, and so the initial value from the temporary `ClassA` constructed via direct-initialization is lost by the copy constructor that doesn't copy that value.

If you initialize `ClassA::myVal` to the value from the object being copied in `ClassA`'s copy constructor, you get the behavior you expect:

```
ClassA(const ClassA& other) : myVal(other.myVal) {
    std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8f415f1361ecf31)